# Remove Stack Overflow tag facebook-user-support

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, clean-up

I noticed today a question with the [facebook-user-support](/questions/tagged/facebook-user-support).  Clicking on the tag showed me that there are 2 questions associated with this tag.

Since every Facebook user question on Stack Overflow is being closed as off-topic, I suggest that the facebook-user-support tag be deleted.

Comment: Excellent catch.  We definitely don't need tags that *encourage* off-topic questions.

Comment: It appears to be non-existant right now.  Perhaps it would be better to request a blacklisting as it's not what SO is meant to be, a FB support site.

Comment: @Jeff: genesis removed the tag from those 2 questions.

Comment: Leave the tag, but rig it so that it blows whenever someone tries to use it.